How can I only open the unexpectedBracket checking in VSCODE?
I would like to disable the general bracket pair colorization (as I want to color bracket by (,[,{, etc, but not nesting level, I did this using the Highlight extension). But I still want to use the unmatched bracket detection (editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket). Is there a way to do so? The only switch I find is "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled", but this changes the 2 colorizations simultaneously.

our of curiosity, what happens with your extension if you customize VS Code's colours for all levels of matched brackets to transparent, or regular text colour?
